# WPF Datagrids virtualization

Tags: wpf, datagrid, virtualization

I am trying to bypass virtualization problems associated with WPF Datagrids by having two levels of arrangement of my data.

The row for each country is the header row and the employees in that country are shown on clicking of the header row.

Essentially, I am trying to make each element of the datagrid as a listview item.

Here are my queries. Any help will be appreciated.

1. I want the Country row to span all the columns so that it appears
   like a header row
2. I don't want the column headers to appear below each country when the header row is clicked
3. I want the data in the country specific data rows to align with the main Grid's
   columns.

If there is any other better way to solve this problem, please do provide the details/references.

[image]

```
    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView Name="InnerGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding EmpCollection}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="EmpId">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Empid}">

                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">

                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Country">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Empid}">

                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Phone">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Phone}">

                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Date">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}">

                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```